# How to create model function with where condition conditions as array

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

the execution logic will be as follows.

```
$condition = '';
if($_POST['name']!=''){
    $condition = $condition + 'cus.C_name' => $_POST['cname'];
}
if($_POST['cno']!=''){
    $condition = $condition + 'cus.C_name' => $_POST['cno'];
}
```

where clause will have to contain

```
array('cus.C_name' => $_POST['cname'],'cus.C_name' => $_POST['cno'])
```

if the post variable is exists it will append to array. how i do this

Comment: "I want" is a very bad way to start your question. What have you tried to solve / achieve this?

Comment: If you want to achive this then you need to put same name to html control as db fields i.e. cus.cno = $_POST['cno] so in lopp you can use same variable to make it dynamic

Comment: Do you need `and` / `or` condition

Comment: @NarendraSisodia- if i used or condition can i get correct result

Comment: I'm newer to stack overflow site. i'm very sorry for my unpolite way - Epodax

Comment: It all depends on you are you storing both dynamic values within `cname` i.e. its consists name or any number if `cno` is your `id` than you need to differentiate it as said by Lalit

Comment: actually i want filtered data from database, data entered by several fields. those data sent by js. all things are well. but i'm unable to write where clause with codeigniter with array.

Comment: if some one select name and have to filtered by name or if some one entered any filter or every filter he will able to get correct value

Comment: C_name is my database value and name is send by js function

Comment: Can you please us the table structure

Comment: C_name, C_id,C_address,C_title, C_init those fields i need to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot produce

```
array('cus.C_name' => $_POST['cname'],'cus.C_name' => $_POST['cno']);
```

basically this array will produce

```
array('cus.C_name' => $_POST['cno']);
```

because both array key is same and it will be one element;

You can do it following way

```
    if($_POST['name']!='')
    {
        $this->db->where('cus.C_name',$_POST['cname']);
    }

    if($_POST['cno']!='')
    {            
        $this->db->where('cus.C_name',$_POST['cno']);            
    }
```

This will produce your where condition as you wanted.
**Becarefull**:If your both name and cno is not empty it will produce both where condition and you will get empty result because same column cannot have both value.

Better use `$this->input->post('name')` Enabling CI `url` helper instead of `$_POST['name']`

Hope you understand and it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong than it would help you..

```
if($_POST['cname'] != ''){
   $this->db->where('cus.C_name', $_POST['cname']);
}

if($_POST['cno'] != ''){
   $this->db->where('cus.C_id', $_POST['cno']);
}
```

and use ci methods like `$this->model->post()` or `$this->model->get()`

Comment: yes. thats the way i want. but there is a problem. those post values are sent from filters. if some one enter only name for filter the values, i have to check only name. if both 2 conditions have to be considered